Load is switching between 0V and overcurrent in the pulsed drain biasing circuit for a Power Amplifier
Given below is a block diagram of an evaluation-board.
It is a pulsed biasing board to a PA. It is designed to produce a pulsed-drain and pulsed-gate signal for the biasing of GaN Power Amplifiers.
I have implemented the hardware circuit of the highlighted part of the block-diagram to check only the generation of pulsed drain-pulse(VDD_PA signal)

The evaluation board schematic related to the Drain-pulse generation is as follows

The reference links for the User-guide and documentation:-
https://www.analog.com/en/resources/evaluation-hardware-and-software/evaluation-boards-kits/adpulserplusebz.html#eb-overview
https://wiki.analog.com/resources/eval/developer-kits/pulser-plus
Please have a look at the above reference links.
I have 2 Power amplifiers which requires drain pulse of 28V and 50V respectively and the maximum load current can be upto 15A. So I need the above design to work for both the cases.
Following is the schematic of the hardware circuit i am testing. It is a part of the evaluation board schematic which is related to drain-pulse generation only. I am not connecting the crowbar circuit and the current sense monitoring chip(LT1999)

Testing of Hardware Circuit:-
Supply given is 28V. I have connected a load of 16ohms using a rheostat instead of PA for testing of the biasing board.
DRAIN_PULSE_ENABLE to the INP pin of LTC7000ARMSE is: 5V square pulse, frequency=1Hz, 10% duty cycle
The following are the images of the observed results

Pulsed drain output across R62(16R)

 
Observation: Drain pulse output across the load is not turning ON completely. It is just turning ON for some micro seconds and turning OFF and the amplitude is not reaching 28V

At the Imon pin(10th pin) of LTC7000ARMSE

 
Observation: Imon is triggering between 0V and 1.59V for every 1 sec

At the Iset pin the voltage is 1.14V. The Resistance value near the Iset pin is 120K.



At the Fault pin of LTC7000ARMSE
 

5  Gate signal.
I am placing the positive probe of CRO between R22 and R10 and the negative probe at the ground
 
According to the given frequency and duty cycle, The pulse ON-time must be 10% of 1sec, but the Gate signal ON-time is only 20us.

Between the mosfet and the sense resistor


The signal at the Imon pin is fluctuating between overload(1.65V which is above 1.5V) and 0V.
As a result, the signal to the gate of the mosfet is not turning ON completely which inturn is not turning ON the mosfet completely.The mosfet is turning ON for a short time, overcurrent is being detected at the same instant and therefore it is turning off again. This is repeating continuousluy. We are not understanding how an overload condition is occuring.
What may be the reason for this behaviour. And Please suggest the changes if any in the circuit.

If it is necessary to read the documents linked to be able to answer your question then, if those links break (as they inevitably do) then your question also breaks. This means that your question should be more self-contained (possibly with images of relevant parts of the linked information).

It would be interesting to see the signal in picture 6 with 20 µs/div. More than 18 Vpp here should give a hint. What kind of resistor is R4?

@Andyaka I have added the evaluation-board schematic picture now. Please have a look at it.

@Jens The part number of R4 is  ERJD1DFR010U. It is a sense resistor placed in series with the drain of the mosfet for current monitoring purpose
